# Rails scaffold not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm currently doing Michael Hartls Railstutorials and ran into a problem i don't quite grasp.
When i try to generate a User Scaffold with this command

```
benjamins-air-3:demo_app caspar$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I merely get a listing of the options for the rails command, such as this

```
   benjamins-air-3:demo_app caspar$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /Users/caspar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]                                # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash], [--no-old-style-hash]          # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
benjamins-air-3:demo_app caspar$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
benjamins-air-3:demo_app caspar$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.14
benjamins-air-3:demo_app caspar$
```

But no views or controllers are being generated. Any hints as to what I'm missing out on here? Thanks a lot

Comment: Check your `Rails version` and `Ruby version`.May be you are running a `Rails 3` command in `Rails 2` or lower.

Comment: You should run this command from the project root folder

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've created `rails new` using one version of Rails and than changed it in the `Gemfile`. Because of that if you run any `rails generate` command it'll use new version but it'll not detect your directory as any project, so it'll not create anything.